# How to generate android app automatically?

Tags: javascript, android, web-hosting

I have previously created android app in my web host. I just need to get some inputs from user and customize that program according to the user inputs and re generate the android apk. Is there a way to do this?
Thanks in advance..!

Comment: do you compress the files before generating the apk?

Comment: no i do not compress.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a way, you have to follow the below steps :

for user input:

1- create a library.config that gather the user input and place it in your asset folder
   you can use webservice  such as JSON objects for gathering and parsing data

2- now you read that file with the user input from inside your application

For APK generator :

1- You have to create your build file from inside eclipse and place it in your original project

2- Download ANT tools and use the ant release command to generate the APK from your created 
   application

3- Don't forget to run android update project -p , to update your build file in your application

Answer (score 1):

There is another way you can generate the apk from command line. Please go through the following link:

[Build android apk command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html)

You can take further help of above answer for where you want to save the generated apk file.